# OAuth 2.0 on Android for Web login

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I wish to login to a webpage that uses Google Oauth2.0 from native android app.

I was looking into account manager but I don't think it can work

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        Bundle options = new Bundle();

        am.getAuthToken(
            new Account("t....@gmail.com", "com.google"),// Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
            " some scope?",  // Auth scope
            options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
            this,                           // Your activity
            new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
            new Handler(new OnError()));
```

What scope should I use. Or will I have to follow a different way to login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login (#2 may interest you)

> The scope value must begin with the string openid and then include either or both of profile and email. Any permutation of those values will work but the most common will be openid email or openid profile.

As you have not included anything specific I am assuming "openid,email" should work for you and https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ can give you the list of scopes you can use.